# Is there something like generalized Piecewise in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to define a cubic spline as a function in `Mathematica 8` as I've got every `P_{i}` (which, of course, are polynomials of degree 3) for each interval `[x_{i}, x_{i + 1}], i = 0, ..., n`. What I want to do is to define `s` in the interval `[x_{0}, x_{n + 1}]` as `s(x) = P_{i}(x) if x is in [x_{i}, x_{i+1}]`. How can I do that as `n` varies? I was thinking of `Piecewise` but that didn't work.

Comment: Please show what you tried using `Piecewise`.  Also, please consider adding some formatting to your text, as I find it hard to read.

Comment: I didn't try Piecewise at all. There is no use in doing that. I only looked at the documentation and saw that Piecewise works with fixed number of parameters. I need something that varies.

Comment: I am not understanding your request.  Where do the `n` polynomials come from?  Why can you not fill the `Piecewise` expression programmatically?  Do you even need `Piecewise` if the polynomials are a function of `i`?  How is this function going to be used?

Comment: First of all I know that there is built-in function for splines in Mathematica. I want to create that spline by hand. And secondly that's how typically a cubic spline is defined - some polynomial of degree 3 for each of the intervals.

Comment: Ivan I am not trying to give you a hard time.  I simply don't understand.  I suspect I could help you implement whatever function you want if I understood.  It may be completely apparent to others, but if you will indulge me, please add some solid examples of what you desire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does precisely what you ask, if I'm not mistaken. It's a bit ugly though. There are better alternatives.

```
n = 5;
ClearAll[f];
f[x_] = Piecewise[Table[{x^k, (k - 1)/n < x <= k/n}, {k, 0, n}]]
```

[image]

```
f[1/2]

(* ==> 1/8 *)
```

If you want to make the result dependent on the current state of the global variable `n` (which I wouldn't advocate) thne you can replace the `Set` (=) in the definition of `f` with `SetDelayed` (:=), but this implies re-evaluating the `Table` for every call of `f`. Not that bad for small values of n, but I don't like it. Results in that case look like this:

```
n = 2; f[1/2]
n = 5; f[1/2]

(* ==>  1/2 

   ==>  1/8
*)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. So the answer to my main question would be `s[t_] = Piecewise[Table[{P[i][t], x[i] <= t <= x[i + 1]}, {i, 1, n}]]`

Comment: Tell me Sjoerd, when did you understand that this is what he wanted?  Also, were you put off by the statement that `Piecewise` doesn't work?

Comment: @IvanPetkov x[i] <= x <= x[i + 1] is troublesome. You're mixing the function x and the variable x

Comment: @Ivan Thanks for the accept, but normally you'd better delay accepting for a while to encourage more and possibly better answers. You can always change your accept BTW

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'd like to say it's because I'm a genius but, to be honest, the fact that I arrived after an example was added might have contributed. I knew for sure Piecewise should work, so saying it doesn't triggered me to go for precisely that solution.

Comment: @Sjoerd According to my definition your function should be `f[x_] = ...{k, 1, n}]` and not `{k, 0, n}`. This is pure formalism, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand what you are asking for, but going with my best guess, you may find value in this:

```
p = {func1, func2, func3, func4, func5};

s = If[
      1 <= # <= Length@p,
      p[[Floor[#]]][#],
      "Undefined"
    ] &;

s /@ {2.4, 1.2, 3.3, 4.8, 1.3, -2.5}
```

```
{func2[2.4], func1[1.2], func3[3.3], func4[4.8], func1[1.3], "Undefined"}
```

I am sorry if this is not helpful.

Comment: What I what to do is basically similar to the following : 

`f:(0, 1]->R. f[x_] = x ^ k if x is in ((k - 1)/n, k/n], k = 1, ..., n. So if n = 5 then f[1/2] =  1/8 because 1/2 lies in (2/5, 3/5]`

How to define this function in Mathematica?

Answer (score 1):

Ivan, I think there are a number of ways to do what you want, more or less contrived, based on your comment to my first answer.  Perhaps you are looking for the functionality of `Interpolation` most generally.  Example:

```
n = 5;
Table[{k/n, k}, {k, 0, n}]
f = Interpolation[%, InterpolationOrder -> 0];
Plot[f[i], {i, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]