# How can I use Piecewise[] with a variable number of graphs/intervals

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm writing a program to do cubic spline interpolation. Basically the program will piece together cubic polynomials over certain intervals. I would like to graph this result if all possible with piecewise[] or another similar function.

In my code I have my equations in an array that outputs like this (for example):

```
{2+3/4 (-1+X$6836)+1/4 (-1+X$6836)^3,3+3/2 (-2+X$6836)+3/4 (-2+X$6836)^2-1/4 (-2+X$6836)^3}
```

I also have another array that stores the specific intervals to graph over for each equation above, respectively:

```
{{1<=X$6836<=2},{2<=X$6836<=3}}
```

The number of equations in both arrays can be variable so I need to be able to account for this in piecewise[].

Comment: Hasn't this been asked before? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8545524/618728  Is this for a class?

Answer (score 3):

Just to make sure I understand you, you mean something like this?

```
eq = {2 + 3/4 (-1 + x) + 1/4 (-1 + x)^3, 
   3 + 3/2 (-2 + x) + 3/4 (-2 + x)^2 - 1/4 (-2 + x)^3};
cond = {{1 <= x <= 2}, {2 <= x <= 3}};
p = Piecewise[Thread[{eq, cond}]]
```

[image]

Comment: correct. Sorry about all the extraneous ($6836) numbers. I wasn't sure how to get rid of them.

Comment: @mwc33 in the future, a simple use of `ReplaceAll`, shorthand form `/.` will help with that.  Try: `{your expression list} /. X$6836 -> x`